# Standard Deviations of Random Effects

Tags: multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, hierarchical-bayesian, jags, bugs

I would have a question regarding the estimates of the random effects for a model fitted with JAGS.

I want to fit a mixed model of the form:

$$y_{ij}=\beta_{0j}+\beta_{1j}x_{ij}+\beta_2+e_{ij}$$
$$\beta_{0j}=\beta_0+u_{oj}$$
$$\beta_{1j}=\beta_1+u_{1j}$$

to a multilevel dataset.

The depedent variable represents the exam scores of 215 students. The students are nested within 10 different schools and addition to the school membership the sex of each student (0=male, 1=female) and their coursework performance (evaluated by their respective homeroom teacher) are used as explanatory variables.

$\beta_0$ are $\beta_1$ are the grand mean intercept and the grand mean slope respectively, $u_{oj}$ is the school level random intercept, $u_{1j}$ the coursework-random-slope for each school, $\beta_2$ is the fixed coefficient for sex and $e_{ij}$ is the individual error term for each student.

I then used the lmer-function from the lme4 with the following R-Code:

```
LmerModel <- lmer(Score ~ Sex+Coursework+(1+Coursework|School),data=ExamScores,REML=TRUE)
```

The random effects can be examided with:

```
(RanEffects <- ranef(LmerModel)[[1]])

(Intercept)  Coursework
1    5.89423869 -0.04910307
2    1.43080377 -0.04644842
3    8.31017659  0.14094647
4   -0.90741024 -0.04856894
5    4.59540711 -0.04532380
6   -8.45568361 -0.15232113
7    5.43746601  0.08939357
8    0.02736316  0.30705644
9    3.18673364  0.17963781
10 -19.51909510 -0.37526893
```

As expected, the random effects sum up to 0.

```
> sum(RanEffects[,1])
[1] -3.881583e-13
> sum(RanEffects[,2])
[1] -2.396694e-14
```

After having fitted the same model via Jags, I get the following estimates:

```
beta0        80.9262303 3.9681798 0.125484862    0.138711517
beta0j[1]    86.9319060 4.2698080 0.135023185    0.135023185
beta0j[2]    82.1762976 2.9773773 0.094152936    0.094152936
beta0j[3]    89.2713153 3.6627780 0.115827211    0.115827211
beta0j[4]    80.1008348 4.5824356 0.144909338    0.152116520
beta0j[5]    85.4194419 2.1970681 0.069477392    0.069477392
beta0j[6]    72.7949942 5.4111780 0.171116474    0.181186539
beta0j[7]    86.1620795 4.9641975 0.156981709    0.156981709
beta0j[8]    80.4592736 3.6048737 0.113996116    0.115736902
beta0j[9]    83.8921643 2.5353023 0.080173299    0.080173299
beta0j[10]   61.3309814 3.5380058 0.111881565    0.111881565
beta1         0.6696674 0.1372737 0.004340977    0.004340977
beta1j[1]     0.5458513 0.2899696 0.009169645    0.009169645
beta1j[2]     0.6194542 0.1301764 0.004116541    0.004116541
beta1j[3]     0.7667336 0.1787800 0.005653520    0.005653520
beta1j[4]     0.6143964 0.2250353 0.007116241    0.007842907
beta1j[5]     0.6272528 0.1318521 0.004169529    0.004169529
beta1j[6]     0.5530886 0.2106015 0.006659804    0.006971592
beta1j[7]     0.7301077 0.2752130 0.008703001    0.008703001
beta1j[8]     1.0062973 0.3312920 0.010476372    0.016068724
beta1j[9]     0.8268791 0.1288384 0.004074227    0.005779403
beta1j[10]    0.3794871 0.3071646 0.009713397    0.012065800
beta2        -9.1819500 2.0529069 0.064918616    0.064918616
rho           0.3352995 0.4389860 0.013881955    0.017191257
sigma.beta0j 10.7559158 3.6813056 0.116413106    0.124757792
sigma.beta1j  0.3066015 0.2031617 0.006424538    0.011240312
sigma.eij    14.3626411 0.7701986 0.024355818    0.024355818
```

I calculated the random intercept by subtracting the grand mean slope beta0 from each beta0j[i]. However they do not sum up to 0 but to $\approx$ 0.72. The random slops aren't summing up to 0 either.

Furthemore, I calculated standard deviations of the random effects and they do not match sigma.beta0j/sigma.beta1j either.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Thank you very much for your answers!